# String replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this string `var total_res = R4-4R4-5;` and I want to replace `R4-5` substring with `""`,but I have tried this code so far and it doesn't work:

Javascript:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        ss = "R4-5";
        lool = total_res.replace(ss,"");
        alert(lool);//it alerts the same original string
   });    
</script>
```

What is wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you meant to or not, but `total_res` should be declared as a string...like:

```
var total_res = "R4-4R4-5";
```

Using your code, it works like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/rV8Cb/

If you checked your browser's (error) console, you'd see: `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Note that `.replace()` only replaces the first occurrence of the string. You'd have to use a regular expression if you want to replace every occurrence of "R4-5" in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define total_res in quotes.  then it works fine for me.

`var total_res = "R4-4R4-5";`

http://jsfiddle.net/PxJrn/